# How to use NotMapped Properties in a Composite Foreign Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I'm creating a Codefirst from database EF project. The database this is being generated from I am unable to alter in anyway. I have manually created most of the relationships between the tables, however I have hit a wall with a table.

Have two tables

```
T1: FK3
T2: PK1 PK2 PK3
```

The relationship between T1: FK1 FK2 is Hard coded logic.
Because the Table is T1 then FK1 = "Foo" and FK2 = "BAR"

I've created

```
T1
[NotMapped]
FK1 {get {return "FOO"}}
[NotMapped]
FK2 {get {return "BAR"}}
```

Mapped this with fluent api

```
modelBuilder.Entity<T1>
    .HasRequired<T2>
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(f => new {f.FK1, f.FK2, f.FK3 })
```

I get the error:

```
The foreign key component 'FK1' is not a 
declared property on type 'T1'. Verify that it has not been     
explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property.
```

How can I create this relationship? I've tried DataAnnotations fluentapi doesn't seem to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `[NotMapped]` properties as keys. Not mapped means exaclty that - "this is c# code that wont be mapped to the database".

You can however use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Computed)]` and calculate the values on the database : [custom sequence string as sql identity column](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/custom-sequence-string-as-sql-identity-column.aspx)

PS.: The hazzle free way to declare a foreign key is `[ForeignKey]` and just use an `int` to hold the ids.

Comment: I would have to use the .computed to alter the database correct? If so I am unable to alter the database.

Comment: On the PS. I'm not sure what you are saying on it. I have 3 foreign keys for that entity. I've tried data annotation on those, but I still have the same issue since the 2 fields are [Not Mapped]

Comment: Sorry I forgot that you can't change the database. `Computed` tells EF that these values are generated by the database and it should not touch them. If you cant replicate the hard coded logic for T1: FK1 FK2 on the DB, this approach wont work.

Comment: Sadly I'm not able too. If I could I would change the entire way this works :)